# How to pass value from custom object input field to custom controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object

I have two VF pages i need to pass value from my 1 st VF input field to 2nd VF page using common custom controller.

this is My Apex Code;

```
public class Sample{
public Sample(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{}
public String Registration__c.Email_id__c  {get;set;}

    public void email() {
    System.debug('This is your registered email' + Registration__c.Email_id__c);
  }
}
```

this is my Vf Code

```
<apex:page standardController="Registration__c" extensions="Sample"  showheader="False" sidebar="False">
    <apex:messages />

            <apex:form >
                <html>
      <head>
      <title>RegistrationPage</title>

        <span style="display:block; margin:50px auto; text-align:Center;color:black;font-size:150%;">REGISTRATION PAGE - ONE TIME</span>
          <style>

           div.btnGroup1{
          text-align:right;margin-top:-24px;margin-right:100px;
           }
               div.btnGroup2{
          text-align:center;margin-top:30px;margin-right:550px;padding:8px*20px;
           }

       </style>
       </head>
        </html>
            <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection >  

            <apex:inputField required="true" value="{!Registration__c.Email_id__c}"/><br /> <br /> 
            <apex:inputField required="false" value="{!Registration__c.Mobile_number__c}"/><br /> <br /> 
            <apex:inputField required="false" value="{!Registration__c.Employee_number__c}"/>  <br /> <br /> 
             </apex:pageBlockSection>


             <div class="btnGroup2">  
             <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" styleClass="buttonStyle" style="background:thistle ;width:110px;height:25px;font-size: 14px"/>
             </div>



        </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

But i am getting Illegal variable declaration: Registration__c.Email_id__c Error how i can achieve this

Answer (score 2):

You need to change variable initialization in your controller

```
public class Sample{
public Registration__c reg {get;set;}
public Sample(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{
    reg  = (Registration__c)controller.getRecord();
}


    public void email() {
    System.debug('This is your registered email' + reg .Email_id__c);
    // now you can pass the email in parameter or can get that.
  }
}
```

And as you have mention you are using same controller then you can make a wizard where all values in controller will be stored

```
PageReference acctPage = new PageReference('Your page URL);
acctPage.setRedirect(false);
 return acctPage;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to declare an sObject field as variable. This is not possible. Try the below code.

```
public class Sample{
    public Registration__c reg {get; set;}
    public String emailId {get; set;}
    public Sample(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        reg = (Registration__c)Controller.getRecord();
        emailId = reg.Email_id__c;
    }

    public void email() {
        System.debug('This is your registered email' + emailId);
    }
}
```